# UITableView: can't scroll during insertRows

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table and a new row appears from the bottom every second (like a chat). If I try to start scrolling my table during one of the insertions it will not react - I have to lift my finger and start scrolling again. Swift demands I call `performBatchUpdates` on main thread but it looks like it's blocking it for too long. I want to be able to scroll at all times, without interruptions, please help.

Here is a repo with demonstration project and gif:

https://github.com/f3dm76/TableInsertionExample

Comment: I believe this is by design. The table view freezes user interaction as the update occurs. You might find 'UITableView Diffable DataSource' a better fit, all round better choice.